# How to make an operation similar to _mm_extract_epi8 with non-immediate input?

Tags: sse, avx2

What I want is extracting a value from vector using a variable scalar index.

Like `_mm_extract_epi8` / `_mm256_extract_epi8` but with non-immediate input.

(There are some results in the vector, the one with the given index is found out to be *the true result*, the rest are discarded)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Especially, if `index` is in a GPR, the easiest way is probably to store `val` to memory and then `movzx` it into another GPR. Sample implementation using C:

```
uint8_t extract_epu8var(__m256i val, int index) {
    union {
        __m256i m256;
        uint8_t array[32];
    } tmp;
    tmp.m256 = val;
    return tmp.array[index];
}
```

Godbolt translation (note that a lot of overhead happens for stack alignment -- if you don't have an aligned temporary storage area, you could just `vmovdqu` instead of `vmovdqa`): https://godbolt.org/z/Gj6Eadq9r

Comment: Instead of a union here, you could just use `_mm256_store_si256` (or storeu) on a local `alignas(32) uint8_t array[32];`.  Or `alignas(__m256i)`.  Some compilers will choose to over-align the array even if you don't ask for it, when they see this store/reload.  I think all C++ compilers that support Intel intrinsics allow union type-punning, although I have some recollection of hearing that SunCC didn't.  Regardless, an intrinsic store is more idiomatic and immediately recognizable, to my eyes at least, than a union-member assignment.

Comment: But yes, in asm a store/reload is only about 6 cycle latency IIRC (so not much worse than a lane-crossing shuffle plus `pshufb` on Skylake), and quite cheap in terms of uop throughput, especially for the front-end.  And if the compiler *wants* to optimize it into a shuffle with some future instruction-set, or a known-constant index, it can.

Answer (score 1):

So far the best option seem to be using `_mm_shuffle_epi8` for SSE

```
uint8_t extract_epu8var(__m128i val, int index) {
    return (uint8_t)_mm_cvtsi128_si32(
        _mm_shuffle_epi8(val, _mm_cvtsi32_si128(index)));
}
```

Unfortunately this does not scale well for AVX. `vpshufb` does not shuffle across lanes. There is a cross lane shuffle `_mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32`, but the resulting stuff seem to be complicated:

```
uint8_t extract_epu8var(__m256i val, int index) {
    int index_low = index & 0x3;
    int index_high = (index >> 2);
    return (uint8_t)(_mm256_cvtsi256_si32(_mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32(
      val, _mm256_zextsi128_si256(_mm_cvtsi32_si128(index_high))))
      >> (index_low << 3));
}
```